# ModelChoiceForm not creating an empty_label

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I've made a form in django using `ModelChoiceSelect`, and I want to put an `empty_label` on the select widget so the first choice isn't the one that's selected. This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Country, Embassy

class CountryListForm(forms.Form):
    countries = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

What I understand from its [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), I just need to do is pass the `empty_label` attribute a value to create it. I've done it already but the empty choice isn't appearing, what I am doing wrong with this form?

This is what my widget looks like, regardless of any assignment to `empty_label`

[image: Widget]

Answer (score 0):

`empty_label` attribute is optional. By default it is "--------". When this option will be selected the object the form field `countries` will return will be `None`. If you want `None` as option in the field its display string can be set by `empty_label`.

```
countries = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label="Any String You Want None Option")
```

If you dont want `None` option then set `empty_label` to `None`. This will show first object in `queryset` as the first option.

```
countries = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label=None)
```

Comment: I switched my `empty_label` value to be the same as yours but it's still not showing up. See the photo I added into my question.

Comment: Have you passed a default argument? Or made the field required? As per documentation : `Note that if a ModelChoiceField is required and has a default initial value, no empty choice is created (regardless of the value of empty_label).`

Comment: Not sure about being required. The `Country` field in the model are foreign keys.